# What are the guidelines on where to post a programming question?

Tags: support, scope

I just posted a question to https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ but then I thought maybe I should have posted it in stackoverflow.com

I mean, what is the difference between these two? They both for programming questions, right?

What would be the more appropriate one to ask about how to write a plugin for Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer this similar question

[Choosing between stackoverflow.com and programmers.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82988/choosing-between-stackoverflow-com-and-programmers-stackexchange-com/82990#82990)

Answer (score 4):

FAQ is where you should go.

The [Stack Overflow FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) and [the Programmers FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq)